# swift 4 makeToast with Image from url (Kingfisher,Toast-Swift)

Tags: swift, toast, kingfisher

I got a Toast:
I use https://github.com/scalessec/Toast-Swift

```
self.navigationController?.view.makeToast(toastMsg, duration: 1.2, position: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height - 105), title: nil, image: UIImage(named:"myImage", style: nil, completion: nil)
```

how can I change a image to a downloaded Kingfisher image?

```
let Image = ImageDownloader.default.downloadImage(with: URL(string: "myURL...")!)
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: "makeToast()" being... ?

Comment: oh sorry I use https://github.com/scalessec/Toast-Swift